# Got compilation error when installing plyvel

Tags: python, pi-3b+, packages, pip

I got an error while trying to install `plyvel` on my raspberry  (pi 3 B+) with `sudo pip install plyvel` :

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting plyvel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/1d/05e3555abddb49b9a2f3aa1268bec4933bf377ffcad3c1b2630fcfa597eb/plyvel-1.0.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: plyvel
  Building wheel for plyvel (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-6UieGu/plyvel/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-07KIhZ --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
  copying plyvel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
  copying plyvel/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
  running build_ext
  building 'plyvel._plyvel' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:589:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory
   #include "leveldb/db.h"
                          ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for plyvel
  Running setup.py clean for plyvel
Failed to build plyvel
Installing collected packages: plyvel
  Running setup.py install for plyvel ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-6UieGu/plyvel/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-GikxjL/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
    copying plyvel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
    copying plyvel/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
    running build_ext
    building 'plyvel._plyvel' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:589:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory
     #include "leveldb/db.h"
                            ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-6UieGu/plyvel/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-GikxjL/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-6UieGu/plyvel/
```

I trying to install some important dependancies `apt-get install gcc python-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev`

On the compilation it seem not found a file on his own package, weird : `plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:589:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory`

So, I have installed `sudo apt-get install python-leveldb` to have a build of leveldb, nothing new.

Maybe I have to post this issue directly in the plyvel repository but I don't even know first if there is a missing dependancies on the raspberry first. Any idea ?

Thanks for your help & have a good day !

### EDIT:

Have a new error after install some package, as the oficial documentation recommended (read the doc, read the doc !) : `apt-get install libleveldb1v5 libleveldb-dev`.

```
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    plyvel/_plyvel.cpp: In function ‘int __pyx_f_6plyvel_7_plyvel_parse_options(leveldb::Options*, bool, bool, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, int, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
    plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:3401:22: error: ‘struct leveldb::Options’ has no member named ‘max_file_size’; did you mean ‘max_open_files’?
         __pyx_v_options->max_file_size = __pyx_t_4;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Since plyvel 1.0.0, the minimum leveldb version is 1.20. You're using an older version.

See the version history for details: https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html#plyvel-1-0-0